# Keep <style> tag where it is declared in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

**What I'm trying to achieve:** I am trying to create a sort of visual editor where the users can resize and drag elements on a page. Then I will generate a PDF from the updated content.

**How I am doing that:** I open a modal (with `ng-bootstrap`) and display the necessary HTML there. See some sample codes and explanation below,

```
//component.html
<div>
    // HTML for the component 
    <ng-template #thisWillBeShownInModal>
        <html id="htmlForPdfGeneration">
            <head>
                <style>
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            </body>
        </html>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

In component, I'm selecting the `thisWillBeShownInModal` reference and showing it in the modal. The reason for embedding `style` tags in the modal are that the contents inside the modal should be self-sufficient for generating the PDF from it.

**What is the issue:**
The issue is that Angular is hoisting the embedded `style` tags to the top of the page. So, when I generate the PDF, it is not getting any styles as the style definitions are not contained in the HTML I send to the server.

**What I have tried to mitigate this:**
I tried adding an `id` to the embedded `style` tag so that I could capture it during runtime using `document.getElementById` and perhaps inject it dynamically. But Angular removed the `id` too.

So I'm looking for suggestions on how may I achieve my use case. Basically, I need some sort of `iframe` like behavior where there are some self-contained HTML contents. At the very least, I need `style` definitions inside the `htmlForPdfGeneration` tag. Any help and/or pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I am using `Angular` version `10`

Comment: Style tags are evil. well, not really evil, but they are unsafe. You'd be much better off using no style tags and only using css external libraries / files

Comment: I can use an external stylesheet in the front-end. The problem is the server does not know anything about the stylesheets. So, I'll get a style-less PDF which is .. not nice looking. For now, evil is the only thing I have.